# Moving find command from terminal to file giving error

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line

Running

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -execdir bash -c 'd=${1##*/}; ls -1Ad --color=auto "$d"' '-' '{}' ';'
```

on the command line works perfectly but when I move it to my .bashrc file as a function

```
lf() {
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -execdir sh -c 'd=${1##*/}; ls -1Ad --color=auto "$d"' '-' '{}' ';'
}
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: /home/me/.bashrc: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/me/.bashrc: line 19: `lf() {'
```

I assumed it was because of the difference between single and double quotes but I've tried a 100 different combinations and I either get the same error or get incorrect results. I'm missing some fundamental knowledge to move this command from the terminal to a file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `lf () {` instead of `lf() {` ---  Mind the spaces ..

Comment: Spacing doesn't matter here. I'm guessing you previously tried to define `lf` as an alias, and now that's interfering with your new function definition. Make sure to unalias it first.

Comment: Genius. It was that I had aliased it. The spacing didn't matter after unaliased it first. Thanks!